# Converting json output from twitter search api to an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter

I have the following code that searches for tweets with the hashtag "baseball".

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Simple Twitter API Test</h2>";

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "*****",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "*****",
    'consumer_key' => "****",
    'consumer_secret' => "*****"
);
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=#baseball';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The output that i am getting is of the form :

Simple Twitter API Test

```
Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                            [result_type] => recent
                            [iso_language_code] => en
                        )
                [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 22:06:36 +0000 2014
                [id] => 4.37710107788E+17
                [id_str] => 437710107787657216
                [text] => Good day at practice #springtraining #baseball http://t.co/Zu8zJ6qAeI
                [source] => Instagram
                [truncated] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 75486410
                        [id_str] => 75486410
                        [name] => Jimi Mosher
                        [screen_name] => zortyonroids
                        [location] => 
                        [description] => 
                        [url] => 
                        [entities] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Array
                                    (
                                        [urls] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [protected] => 
                        [followers_count] => 12
                        [friends_count] => 161
                        [listed_count] => 0
                        [created_at] => Sat Sep 19 05:58:13 +0000 2009
                        [favourites_count] => 6
                        [utc_offset] => 
                        [time_zone] => 
                        [geo_enabled] => 1
                        [verified] => 
                        [statuses_count] => 50
                        [lang] => en
                        [contributors_enabled] => 
                        [is_translator] => 
                        [is_translation_enabled] => 
                        [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                        [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                        [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                        [profile_background_tile] => 
                        [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000476940795/6c5ab18350233a756b9980dd2a2e84c1_normal.jpeg
                        [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000476940795/6c5ab18350233a756b9980dd2a2e84c1_normal.jpeg
                        [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/75486410/1379568136
                        [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                        [profile_text_color] => 333333
                        [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                        [default_profile] => 1
                        [default_profile_image] => 
                        [following] => 
                        [follow_request_sent] => 
                        [notifications] => 
                    )

                [geo] => 
                [coordinates] => 
                [place] => 
                [contributors] => 
                [retweet_count] => 0
                [favorite_count] => 0
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [hashtags] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => springtraining
                                        [indices] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 21
                                                [1] => 36
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => baseball
                                        [indices] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 37
                                                [1] => 46
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [symbols] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [url] => http://t.co/Zu8zJ6qAeI
                                        [expanded_url] => http://instagram.com/p/kxlYF0yvfD/
                                        [display_url] => instagram.com/p/kxlYF0yvfD/
                                        [indices] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 47
                                                [1] => 69
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [user_mentions] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [favorited] => 
                [retweeted] => 
                [possibly_sensitive] => 
                [lang] => en
            )
```

I would like to print only the 'text' as well as the 'created at' fields
.
I am unable to decode json into an associative array and print it using the following code:

```
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
        echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
```

Please suggest as to what changes should be made to print the associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 2nd parameter of `json_decode` :

```
json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
```

by

```
json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To decode a `json` as an associative array you just need to pass `true` as second parameter

```
json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(), true);
```

From [**documentation**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> assoc
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.